# navigation with kinect question

Tags: navigation, kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
I`m a newer to the ROS,and now I want to do the simulation on my computer with the kinect first,and the final purpose is to do navigation with kinect.So I hope anyone can share your precious experiences about how to do navigation with kinect by steps.
The more detailed, the better!

I trully want to know the steps of using ros to accompish the vision navigation with kinect.By the way,now I have a robot but not the one showed on the ros.org.

Thanks very much!!!
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30653/navigation-with-kinect---question/) by [Ocean](https://answers.ros.org/users/2058/ocean/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2012-03-28

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ocean](https://answers.ros.org/users/2058/ocean/) on 2012-03-28**:
Thank you for your answers and advice! And I trully want to know the steps of using ros to accompish the vision navigation with kinect.By the way,now I have a robot but not the one showed on the ros.org,but the robot is alike TurtleBot

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-03-30**:
You can see this: http://answers.ros.org/question/9087/vslam-based-navigation-with-kinect-where-do-i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using the kinect and doing a simulation are two different things. Do you have a kinect and do you wish to program it? Or do you wish to simulate kinnect data?

There is no way you can achieve navigation with just kinect. You will need a complete mobile robot to do that. Do you have a TurtleBot?

Please describe what you wish to do in detail.

---

Originally posted by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) with karma: 1247 on 2012-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kshitij](https://answers.ros.org/users/1481/kshitij/) on 2012-03-29**:
Is it possible to use slam_gmapping with Kinect? I ask this because gmapping seems to use Laser scans where as Kinect publishes point clouds. Thanks.

**Comment by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on 2012-04-02**:
The gmapping_demo.launch file uses the kinect to do the mapping. The kinect data are presented to the algorithm as though it is coming from a laser. In reality, it is only the point cloud data that is converted to Laser-like data. The answer to your question is yes.